# Linq: filtering a list by time spans in another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of objects. One list has a value and a datetime. The other list has a start and end time. I want to build a new list containing the objects in the first list that fall between any object in the second list's start time and end time plus 8 hours.

I was thinking I could just loop through the list with time spans and use linq to pull out the relevant items in the first list, check for duplicates and if the new list doesn't contain the value add it. That would work but it seems like there should be a way to do this just by using Linq.

Would anyone have an idea on how to do this with just linq?

Comment: Post sample input and desired output, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
values.Where(v => times.Any(t => v.DateTime >= t.StartTime 
                              && v.DateTime <= t.EndTime)
            )
```

Comment: Perfect, that should do it. Thanks! Seems so easy once I see it.